# SQL - Dynamic query won't create table

Tags: sql-server

I would appreciate some help with my query. Below is a piece of code that ran perfectly fine (the table was created and I saw it in the tempdb), but when I move that same code into the stored proc I am creating, the ## table is not longer being created and calling it later results in Invalid Object. Could you please help me out here? Thank you!!

```
    SET @SQLCreateTableVSC = 'CREATE TABLE ##VSC_Temp (['
                        +@VSCColName+'] nvarchar(max)
                        ,['+@moname1+'] nvarchar(max)
                        ,['+@moname2+'] nvarchar(max)
                        ,['+@moname3+'] nvarchar(max)
                        ,['+@moname4+'] nvarchar(max)
                        ,['+@moname5+'] nvarchar(max)
                        ,['+@moname6+'] nvarchar(max)
                        ,['+@moname7+'] nvarchar(max)
                        ,['+@moname8+'] nvarchar(max)
                        ,['+@moname9+'] nvarchar(max)
                        ,['+@moname10+'] nvarchar(max)
                        ,['+@moname11+'] nvarchar(max)
                        ,['+@moname12+'] nvarchar(max)
                        ,['+@moname13+'] nvarchar(max)
                        )'

    execute sp_executeSQL @SQLCreateTableVSC
    , N'@VSCcolname nvarchar(max)
    ,@moname1 nvarchar(max)
    ,@moname2 nvarchar(max)
    ,@moname3 nvarchar(max)
    ,@moname4 nvarchar(max)
    ,@moname5 nvarchar(max)
    ,@moname6 nvarchar(max)
    ,@moname7 nvarchar(max)
    ,@moname8 nvarchar(max)
    ,@moname9 nvarchar(max)
    ,@moname10 nvarchar(max)
    ,@moname11 nvarchar(max)
    ,@moname12 nvarchar(max)
    ,@moname13 nvarchar(max)'
    , @VSCcolname=@VSCcolname
    , @moname1=@moname1
    , @moname2=@moname2
    , @moname3=@moname3
    , @moname4=@moname4
    , @moname5=@moname5
    , @moname6=@moname6
    , @moname7=@moname7
    , @moname8=@moname8
    , @moname9=@moname9
    , @moname10=@moname10
    , @moname11=@moname11
    , @moname12=@moname12
    , @moname13=@moname13
```

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. That code is product specific.

Comment: Yes, having the tag of sql when your code is not really sql but rather SQL Server specific will cause people who watch the sql tag to not be happy with you.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create your table first then it will be available in the dynamic sql

this works

```
create table #temp3 (id int)
exec ('insert #temp3 values(1)')

select * from #temp3
```

this will not work

```
exec ('create table #temp2 (id int)
     insert #temp2 values(1)')

select * from #temp2
```

Comment: The issue I have is that I don't know how to create column names as variables outside of dynamic SQL...can that be done?